# How to link a non-standard header file into a C compiler

Tags: c, compiler-construction, header-files, gnuplot

I'm trying to use a non-standard header file (http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot). Its used in lots of codes in various different places on my computer.  Currently I have to put the header file and the object file in every folder which its needed with the preprocessor directive:

```
#include "gnuplot_i.h"
```

In the file.  Is there a way by which I can put the header file in one place so I can reference it like other standard header file.  Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile with `-I<directory>`

E.g.

compile with `-I/usr/local/gnuplot/inc`.

Also it might be worth your reading up on include paths and the difference between:

```
#include <include_file.h>
```

and

```
#include "include_file.h"
```

Linking in an object file needs to be done explicitly the same way as a C file, which means (I believe) that you need a full path. However if you archive it into a proper library then you can use `-l<library name>` and `-L<library path>` instead. E.g.

```
gcc -I/usr/local/gnuplot/inc -L/usr/local/gnuplot/lib -lgnuplot -o my_prog my_prog.c
```

Comment: That's I as in Igloo, not l as in lollypop. Just in case your browser renders it like mine and you can't tell which is which.

Comment: @Aaron I know how to do it (ctrl-K), I just didn't think of it. Thanks though - I'll make sure to remember it for next time. Also I wanted to get the first answer in on such an easy question. It's my first day here :)

Comment: No sweat; you got your +1 from me :-)

Answer (score 2):

Most compilers have a flag `-I` that lets you add a directory of your choosing to the search path for include files.